# Laravel 8 The provided two factor authentication code was invalid

Tags: laravel-8

I have used laravel fortify without jetstream.
The 2FA is always returning false.

Recovery codes are working but the 6 digit code always return false

```php
class TwoFactorAuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
  
    ... 
    
    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate a new session using the two factor authentication code.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\TwoFactorLoginRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function store(TwoFactorLoginRequest $request)
    {
        $user = $request->challengedUser();

        if ($code = $request->validRecoveryCode()) {
            $user->replaceRecoveryCode($code);
        } elseif (! $request->hasValidCode()) {  // This always return false
            return app(FailedTwoFactorLoginResponse::class);
        }

        $this->guard->login($user, $request->remember());

        return app(TwoFactorLoginResponse::class);
    }
  
}
```

#### $request->hasValidCode()

```php
public function hasValidCode()
    {
        return $this->code && app(TwoFactorAuthenticationProvider::class)->verify(
            decrypt($this->challengedUser()->two_factor_secret), $this->code
        );
    }
```

I haven't changed the fortify backend. I have only converted the frontend with bootstrap.

Comment: Running into same issue.  The weird thing is I am able to "confirm" two factor authentication with a code by making a post to `/user/confirmed-two-factor-authentication` as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#confirming-two-factor-authentication), but on login where it also confirms a code (and uses same Provider for verification), it fails

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post whilst searching for for an answer to the same question. I eventually found that my servers time was out by about 2 minutes. I enabled a NTP to keep the time synchronized and 2FA in Laravel started working without issues.

Comment: i will check that on my end